# Difficulty accessing External Storage on Android

Tags: android

I am trying to access external storage on my Android App in order to access a log file so I created:

```
new File(getExternalFilesDir(null),"log.txt");
```

And then created this file in the root of my Android device.

To test the existence of the file I ran:

```
if (log!=null)
    {
        return log.exists();
    }
    return false;
```

But regardless of the files presence or lack thereof it returns false.

To find the location of where I was referencing I ran:

```
System.out.println(log.getAbsolutePath());
```

Which returns

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.supportmeplus.betatester/files/log.txt
```

Where is this? I'd just like to access a log file that can be accessed from outside of the app later on (on a computer). Does this have to do with the fact that i'm test-running the app with an emulator?

Thanks

Comment: what is log here ? How do u initialize it ?

Comment: Post more details, better a full test case. And point out what's wrong with it.